# The connection string property has not been initialized. (system.data) in Microsoft Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm very much new to SQL Server and it's Management studio. And I happened to export the data from it. But then Management studio is throwing an error in "SQL Server Import and Export Widget". I'm attaching a screenshot.[image]

Not able to understand what could be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Connection string is empty:
[image]

Insert correction connection string:
[image]

Or use another data provider:[image]

Comment: Thank you. But From where can I find correct Connection String?

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada look at last picture: select SQL Native Client, set your SQL server name and database